# MCP error on command prompt when click on .bat

Tags: javascript, python, windows, file, minecraft

Hi I was trying to make a Minecraft client with MCP(Mod Coder Pack link: http://www.modcoderpack.com/.  But got a problem when I click on .bat Windows Batch File.  It gives me this error on command prompt.
[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujsmg.png)

I have been facing this problem for 3 days.
I hope somebody can fixed this problem.

Comment: It sounds to me like you missed a step and forgot to update or extract some files. Try these instructions: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Mods/Creating_mods/Setting_up_the_MCP_workspace

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe A Answer**

Hi, have you tried reinstalling Mod Coders Pack (MCP) cause sometimes while downloading files it can not actually download a few, if that didn't work. then try updating java (this prob wont work) im not sure about anything else

EDIT: Just realised try installing Python 3.6.5 if you haven't yet